# Auth0 Angular 2. Error when using AuthHttp

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm trying to secure my SPA application by using Auth0 and JWT. If Im doing http.get with "normal" Http from @angular/http, it's working fine, but when I'm doing completely same call with AuthHttp, just nothing happen and no errrors.
This is my service:

```
constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) {

  }

  loadItems(): Observable<FrontItemDto[]> {
    return this.authHttp.get ( `${ServiceSettings.ApiUrl}/front` )
      .map ( res => {
        res.json ();
      } )
      .catch ( (error: any) => Observable.throw ( error.json ().error || 'Server error' ) );
  }
```

This is app.module

```
  import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
    ...
    export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
      return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        tokenName: 'token',
        tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('token')),
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
      }), http, options);
    }
....
providers: [
    ...
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: What happens if you set `noJwtError` within the `AuthConfig` object to `true`? Does it then conitune with a regular http request?

Comment: @KimKern, seems like it's ok now.

Comment: @KimKern, please add this as answer.

Comment: I would've expected it to do an unauthenticated request now that you've set the flag. Does your backend already require authentication? If you look in the DevTools, Network tab, is the Authentication header set? With `noJwtError` set to false (default), AuthHttp won't send a request if it can't access the token or if it is expired/invalid. Did you make sure that the token stored is accessible with `sessionStorage.getItem('token')` from the console and if the returned token is valid (e.g. with the https://jwt.io debugger). If it really works, I'll be happy to add it as an answer :)

Comment: @KimKern, yes, WebApi already require authorization. Semes like now there is no Bearer Header was sent.

Comment: Ok, so you're requests fail now without the Bearer header?! Did you check your token in your sessionStorage? Is it available and valid?

Comment: @KimKern, thanks, it's working now (not completely, but this on server side this time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting `noJwtError` within the `AuthConfig` object to `true`, requests with an invalid or missing token will go through with a regular HTTP request (without authentication).

If this is the case, you should check whether your token can be accessed at the provided location (here `sessionStorage.getItem('token')` from the DevTools console) and if the provided token is valid. To check the validity, you can for example use the token debugger by https://jwt.io.